# Install wordpress envato plugin with composer.json

Tags: json, composer-php

I need to install Envato plugin with composer.json, but i don't know how to do. 
There is a very big list of plugins on wordpress.org and wpackagist.org, for add a string in composer and recall the plugin, but this list doesn't include the envato plugins.

Comment: In other words: the "envato plugin" you are looking for is not in the wpackagist.org list? http://wpackagist.org/search?q=envato&type=any Which plugin are you looking for?

Comment: I want to install media-grid or essential-grid, here the envato link:
http://codecanyon.net/item/essential-grid-wordpress-plugin/7563340
http://codecanyon.net/item/media-grid-wordpress-responsive-portfolio/2218545

They are plugins with many advanced features compare to wordpress.org plugins.

Comment: Both plugins are very nice feature-wise. But.. both have a commercial license. Seems one would have to buy them and install them manually. (I doubt that they give these plugins away for free (via a simple Composer package fetch). That would only make sense, if they protect their code and request an API key from the consumer, after the installation to activate the plugin. Can't find any infos about that.)

Comment: This could be useful: https://github.com/envato/envato-wordpress-toolkit (I think this plugin helps to interact with the Envato API and allows buying and fetching plugins. Not tested.) Its not possible to fetch it with Composer.

Comment: I had bought the license some months ago for this plugins, I find a script for Envato API Key, but i think i can contact directly the developer of this plugin for a valid solution. Yeah i don't think there is a way for have this plugins free. Thanks very much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same shoe.
Now it is possible to install Envato products (WordPress themes and plugins) as a Composer package.

You need to install [Composer plugin for Envato](https://packagist.org/packages/szepeviktor/composer-envato) globally.

```
composer global require --update-no-dev szepeviktor/composer-envato
```

And list your purchased item ID-s in `~/.composer/config.json`